# How to import Jfugues library on Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, jfugue

I coded a java application with eclipse using jfugues library for my computer. I was trying to build the same application for my android phone using Android Studio but I can't figure out how to import this jfugues library. Can someone explain me please how to do it step by step

Comment: you must have midi to import

Comment: @ArchuMohan explains me how to use it please

Comment: It's my understanding that the JVM on Android does not include support for the javax.sound.midi package.